# Roxygen2 error when creating documentation

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to document my package functions using roxygen but i keep having the same error mistake when require roxygen to document:

```
==> devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Error: ‘roxygen2’ >= >= 6.1.0 must be installed for this functionality.
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

This answer seems self explanatory, the only problem is that i have roxygen2 6.1.1 installed...

```
> devtools::session_info()
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
 os       Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS          
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    pt_PT.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Lisbon               
 date     2019-04-25                  

─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date       lib source        
 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 backports     1.1.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 callr         3.2.0   2019-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cli           1.1.0   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 commonmark    1.7     2018-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 devtools    * 2.0.2   2019-04-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 digest        0.6.18  2018-10-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fs            1.2.7   2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 glue          1.3.1   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 packrat       0.5.0   2018-11-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgbuild      1.0.3   2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgload       1.0.2   2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 prettyunits   1.0.2   2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 processx      3.3.0   2019-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ps            1.3.0   2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 R6            2.4.0   2019-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rcmdcheck     1.3.2   2018-11-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 Rcpp          1.0.1   2019-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 remotes       2.0.4   2019-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rlang         0.3.4   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 roxygen2      6.1.1   2018-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rstudioapi    0.10    2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 stringi       1.4.3   2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 testthat      2.1.1   2019-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 usethis     * 1.5.0   2019-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 withr         2.1.2   2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xml2          1.2.0   2018-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 xopen         1.0.0   2018-09-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 yaml          2.2.0   2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)

[1] /home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3
[2] /home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib-ext/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3
[3] /home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib-R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3
```

I am using Packrat and has you can see above i have 3 paths. I have installed the package on all 3 and try loading the package from all 3 individually with no result:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3"    
[2] "/home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib-ext/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3"
[3] "/home/pedro/lemonPKG/packrat/lib-R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.5.3"  
> lapply(.libPaths(), dir)
[[1]]
  [1] "askpass"      "assertthat"   "backports"    "base64enc"   
  [5] "BH"           "Boruta"       "brew"         "broom"       
  [9] "callr"        "caret"        "cellranger"   "cli"         
 [13] "clipr"        "clisymbols"   "colorspace"   "commonmark"  
 [17] "crayon"       "curl"         "data.table"   "DBI"         
 [21] "dbplyr"       "desc"         "devtools"     "digest"      
 [25] "dplyr"        "ellipsis"     "evaluate"     "fansi"       
 [29] "forcats"      "foreach"      "fs"           "generics"    
 [33] "ggplot2"      "gh"           "git2r"        "glue"        
 [37] "gower"        "gtable"       "haven"        "highr"       
 [41] "hms"          "htmltools"    "httr"         "ini"         
 [45] "ipred"        "iterators"    "jsonlite"     "knitr"       
 [49] "labeling"     "lava"         "lazyeval"     "lubridate"   
 [53] "magrittr"     "markdown"     "memoise"      "mime"        
 [57] "ModelMetrics" "modelr"       "munsell"      "numDeriv"    
 [61] "openssl"      "packrat"      "pillar"       "pkgbuild"    
 [65] "pkgconfig"    "pkgload"      "plogr"        "plyr"        
 [69] "praise"       "prettyunits"  "pROC"         "processx"    
 [73] "prodlim"      "progress"     "ps"           "purrr"       
 [77] "R6"           "ranger"       "rcmdcheck"    "RColorBrewer"
 [81] "Rcpp"         "RcppEigen"    "RcppRoll"     "readr"       
 [85] "readxl"       "recipes"      "rematch"      "remotes"     
 [89] "reprex"       "reshape2"     "rlang"        "rmarkdown"   
 [93] "roxygen2"     "rprojroot"    "rstudioapi"   "rvest"       
 [97] "scales"       "selectr"      "sessioninfo"  "SQUAREM"     
[101] "stringi"      "stringr"      "sys"          "testthat"    
[105] "tibble"       "tidyr"        "tidyselect"   "tidyverse"   
[109] "timeDate"     "tinytex"      "usethis"      "utf8"        
[113] "viridisLite"  "whisker"      "withr"        "xfun"        
[117] "xml2"         "xopen"        "yaml"        

[[2]]
[1] "roxygen2"

[[3]]
 [1] "base"       "boot"       "class"      "cluster"    "codetools" 
 [6] "compiler"   "datasets"   "foreign"    "graphics"   "grDevices" 
[11] "grid"       "KernSmooth" "lattice"    "MASS"       "Matrix"    
[16] "methods"    "mgcv"       "nlme"       "nnet"       "parallel"  
[21] "roxygen2"   "rpart"      "spatial"    "splines"    "stats"     
[26] "stats4"     "survival"   "tcltk"      "tools"      "utils"
```

This is my first package and therefore this might be a small question but i haven't found any documentation regarding this issue with roxygen. Might it be some problem with packrat? Any help or lead is appreciated!

Thanks